# How can I test data exchange formats and what kind of metrics should I use to evaluate them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am developing in WebAPI and I came across a lot of data exchange formats to use in place of JSON, I would like to know what would be the best way to evaluate the formats, if there are any specific tools this or other forms of testing.
   Among the formats that I must test are:
    BSON
    CBOR
    FlatBuffers
    MessagePack
    Protocol Buffers
    Thrift

I wish I could use some metrics for this task, I'm not looking for a specific answer but a more concise way of starting those tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google came up with this:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ion/ion-performance-benchmarks.html#ion-vs-json-vs-protobuf-vs-messagepack-vs-cbor

I think it should guide you. It will all come down to two important choices - 1) your usage characteristics which will guide you to the most efficient protocols for your usage, and 2) are you going to impact your possible interoperability, re-use, testing debugging etc by going with something rather than bulk standard JSON?

also 3) depending on point 1) will it actually make a difference to overall system performance?

BTW the link is really pushing ION, but you get all the other information about your candidates as an aside :)

Comment: That's why I asked the question, pretty much all formats are pushing for themselves, I want to make a measurement to be able to set the priorities of the project, find the best way to do this and get a sense of performance of each of them. Thanks for the answer :D, that's a good point to start this task.